# Upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension of a module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm currently trying to solve the following exercise in commutative algebra.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, $M$ an $R$-module. Let $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Denote by $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ the residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$.
Define the *fiber* $M(\mathfrak{p})$ of $M$ in $\mathfrak{p}$ to be the $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$-vector space $M_\mathfrak{p} / \mathfrak{p}M_\mathfrak{p}$, where the indexed $\mathfrak{p}$ denotes the localization at $\mathfrak{p}$. Show that, if $M$ is finitely generated, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the set $A_n := \lbrace \mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R): \dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak{p})} M(\mathfrak{p}) \leq n \rbrace$ is open.

Here's my idea so far. Fix some $\mathfrak{p}$ and suppose the dimension of $M(\mathfrak{p})$ is less than or equal to $n$. Choose generators $b_1, \ldots, b_n$. By Nakayama, we can lift these to generators $m_1, \ldots, m_n$ of $M_\mathfrak{p}$.

The next steps would be to lift this to generators of $M$ and to encode the surjection $R^n \to M$, which assigns to the $i$-th standard basis vector the $i$-th generator of $M$, an overdetermined matrix of some sort. The surjectivity then accounts to the fact that some quadratic minor of this matrix must not vanish, thus expressing $A_n$ as a union of principal open subsets. However, I don't see how this should be possible without any further assumptions on noetherianness etc., which leads me to believe I'm not on the right track with this approach. Any comments on this would be welcome, especially a pointer on how to continue this line of thought (if possible) or how to fix it.

I am not too familiar with the language of schemes, so I'd appreciate solutions that do not make substantial use of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Why do you need Noetherianness?

Comment: @Mohan, I'm not sure if I do. My primary goal was to represent the surjection $R^n \to M$ as a matrix, and I was not sure how to do that. If the ring were noetherian, $M$ would be finitely presented and it would be easier to talk about matrices. But again, as stated in the question, I'm not even sure if one needs to talk about matrices in order to obtain the statement, perhaps there is an easier and more conceptual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose localization $M_p$ is generated by $n$ elements $\frac{m_i}{s_i}$ over $R_p$, then $\frac{m_i}{1}$ also generate $M_p$. We get the map $R^n \to M$ sending the standard basis to $m_i$'s, set $C$ to be the cokernel of that map, then $C_p \cong 0$.

Then the map $R^n \to M$ is surjective on the $U=\operatorname{Spec}(R)\backslash \operatorname{Supp}(C)$, but $U$ is open, since $\operatorname{Supp}(C)$ is closed because $C$ is finitely generated.

So, if there is a point $p \in A_n$ there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of that point in $A_n$.